# Arrays combinations as arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
const data = [
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
];
```

I use the following function that gives me the combinations of the three arrays:

```
const combinations = data.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.reduce((r, v) => {
    return r.concat(b.map(w => {
        return [].concat(v, w);
    }));
  }, []);
});
```

The result of combinations is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
]
```

The above function generates the combinations of all the arrays values, now I want to generate the combinations based on some criteria, I want to generate it based on relations attributes, so I can have the following results:

```
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
]
```

]

To achieve that i change the above function to:

```
const combinations = data.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.reduce((r, v) => {
    return r.concat(b.map(w => {
      let m = true;
      if (w.relations.length) {
        const relations = w.relations.map(relation => ({ level: relation.level, id: relation.items[0] }));
        const relation = relations.find(relation => relation.level === v.level);
        if (relation.id !== v._id) {
                    m = false;
                }
      }
        return m ? [].concat(v, w) : [];
    }));
  }, []);
});
```

But it didn't work correctly!

**EDIT !!**
I found I case when the accepted answer returns an empty array.

```
const data = [
    [
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e85",
            level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
            name: "international",
            relations: []
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e87",
            level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc",
            name: "india mco",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e85"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7dbcdd470fb358a11f",
            level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc",
            name: "africa zone",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e85"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e8a",
            level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
            name: "india",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e85"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
                },
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e87"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb358a0ad",
            level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
            name: "nepal",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e85"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
                },
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e87"],
                    level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc",
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e9b",
            level: "5f22c61b80556e32cf0ca908",
            name: "sanofi group (paul hudson)",
            relations: [],
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e9d",
            level: "5f22c61b80556e32cf0ca909",
            name: "general medicines gbu (olivier charmeil)",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e9b"],
                    level: "5f22c61b80556e32cf0ca908",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e9e",
            level: "5f22c61b80556e32cf0ca909",
            name: "general medicines gbu (olivier charmeil)2222",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["5fac3f7cbcdd470fb3589e9b"],
                    level: "5f22c61b80556e32cf0ca908",
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
];
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here's a simpler version of data:

```
const data = [
    [
        {
            _id: "1",
            level: "l1",
            name: "international",
            relations: []
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "2",
            level: "l2",
            name: "india mco",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["1"],
                    level: "l1",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "3",
            level: "l2",
            name: "africa zone",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["1"],
                    level: "l1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            _id: "4",
            level: "l3",
            name: "india",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["1"],
                    level: "l1",
                },
                {
                    items: ["2"],
                    level: "l2",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            _id: "5",
            level: "l3",
            name: "nepal",
            relations: [
                {
                    items: ["1"],
                    level: "l1",
                },
                {
                    items: ["2"],
                    level: "l2",
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
];
```

And the desired result:

```
[
  [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "level": "l1",
      "name": "international",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "level": "l2",
      "name": "india mco",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "1"
          ],
          "level": "l1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "4",
      "level": "l3",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "1"
          ],
          "level": "l1"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "2"
          ],
          "level": "l2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "level": "l1",
      "name": "international",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      "level": "l2",
      "name": "india mco",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "1"
          ],
          "level": "l1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5",
      "level": "l3",
      "name": "nepal",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "1"
          ],
          "level": "l1"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "2"
          ],
          "level": "l2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
]
```

Only two valid combinations.
EX: it should be not be in the list the following combination: **international - `africa zone` - nepal**, since **nepal** second relation had **items: ["2"]**, which is **`india mco`** not **`africa zone`**

Comment: It's not immediately clear why for example `digital` suddenly appears 3 times in the desired result but only once in the original data. Please rephrase your question, say _why_ the current function does not work and what the _exact_ criteria are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter `b`, instead of returning an empty array, because the empty array does not exclude the actual set of being used as result, but only to exclude `v` and `w` objects and include objects from the following array.

```js
const
    data = [[{ _id: "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0", level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb", name: "asia", relations: [] }, { _id: "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f", level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb", name: "europe", relations: [] }], [{ _id: "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5", level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd", name: "india", relations: [{ items: ["5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb" }, { items: ["5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc" }] }, { _id: "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0", level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd", name: "italy", relations: [{ items: ["5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb" }, { items: ["5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc" }] }, { _id: "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26", level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd", name: "malaysia", relations: [{ items: ["5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb" }, { items: ["5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"], level: "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc" }] }], [{ _id: "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf", level: "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff", name: "digital", relations: [] }]],
    combinations = data.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.reduce((r, v) => {
            return r.concat(b
                .filter(({ relations }) =>
                    !relations.length ||
                    relations.some(({ items, level }) => level === v.level && items[0] === v._id)
                )
                .map(w => [].concat(v, w))
            );
        }, []);
    });

console.log(combinations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hello @Nina, I found a case in which your answer didn't work and instead gives me an empty array.
See my edit, please.

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw. it would be much easier, if you replace unredable `id`/`level` values to more some readable, like colors or items or at least with some small numbers. the bastract from makes it nearly impossible to understand what you like to get without having some tools and time to visualize the problem. the actually used algo filters unwanted items out. maybe this is the problem, because if some item is unwanted the whole sub product is filtered out. maybe a diagram would help with simplified node descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clearer to think about this in terms of recursion rather than many nested array functions.

---

#### By Order

The simplest case presented is giving every possible combination from the 3 sub-arrays.

sub-arrays:

```
1       2        3
asia    india    digital
europe  italy    
        malaysia
```

unique combinations:

```
1       2        3
asia    india    digital
asia    italy    digital
asia    malaysia digital
europe  india    digital
europe  italy    digital
europe  malaysia digital
```

You already show how to do this with array functions. With recursion, the same can be achieved like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vahz3n64/

```js
function getCombinationsByOrder() {
   let recur = (iarray) => {
      var a = [];
      var temp = [];

      if(iarray === data.length-1) {
         return (data[iarray]);
      } else {
         temp = recur(iarray + 1);

         for(var i=0;i<data[iarray].length;i++) {
            for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++) {
               a.push([data[iarray][i], temp[j]].flat());
            };
         };

         return a;
      };
   };

   return recur(0);
};

const data = [
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
];

console.log(getCombinationsByOrder());
```

---

#### By Level

This is getting into combinations by criteria. When filtering by level, it is assumed that a match is included if the `level` value of a given element is found within the `relations` array of an element in the next sub-array. EDIT: if the `relations` array is empty, then that element is also included.

For example, `asia` in the first sub-array has a level of `5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb`. So, `india` in the next sub-array should be included, because it's `relations` array has an entry with that level in it.

It doesn't seem like this is intended to be the only criteria, but in any case, the result would be:

```
1       2        3
asia    india    digital
asia    italy    digital
asia    malaysia digital
europe  india    digital
europe  italy    digital
europe  malaysia digital
```

This filtering can be achieved like this: https://jsfiddle.net/35kqbp18/

```js
function getCombinationsByLevel() {
   let recur = (iarray, level) => {
      var a = [];
      var temp = [];
      var arr = [];

      if(level !== null) {
         for(var i=0;i<data[iarray].length;i++) {
            if(checkHasLevel(data[iarray][i], level)) {
               arr.push(data[iarray][i]);
            };
         };
      } else {
         arr = data[iarray];
      };

      if(iarray === data.length-1) {
         return (arr);
      } else {
         for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            temp = recur(iarray + 1, arr[i].level);

            if(temp.length !== 0) {
               for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++) {
                  a.push([arr[i], temp[j]].flat()); //parsing to prevent circular object
               };
            } else {
               a.push(arr[i]);
            }
         };

         return a;
      };
   };

   let checkHasLevel = (obj, level) => {
      if(obj.relations.length === 0) {
         return true;
      };

      for(var i=0;i<obj.relations.length;i++) {
         if(obj.relations[i].level === level) {
            return true;
         };
      };

      return false;
   };

   return recur(0, null);
};

const data = [
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
];

console.log(getCombinationsByLevel());
```

---

#### By ID

This follows the same logic as filtering by level, but instead using the `_id` value from one element and searching for it in the `relations` array (within `items`) of an element in the next sub-array. EDIT: if the `relations` array is empty, then that element is also included.

For example, `asia` in the first sub-array has an ID of `5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0`. So, `india` in the next sub-array should be included, because its `relations` array has an entry with that ID in it.

The results of this would be:

```
1       2        3
asia    india    digital
asia    malaysia digital
europe  italy    digital
```

This filtering can be achieved like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5apx7foq/

```js
function getCombinationsById() {
   let recur = (iarray, id) => {
      var a = [];
      var temp = [];
      var arr = [];

      if(id !== null) {
         for(var i=0;i<data[iarray].length;i++) {
            if(checkHasId(data[iarray][i], id)) {
               arr.push(data[iarray][i]);
            };
         };
      } else {
         arr = data[iarray];
      };

      if(iarray === data.length-1) {
         return (arr);
      } else {
         for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            temp = recur(iarray + 1, arr[i]._id);

            if(temp.length !== 0) {
               for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++) {
                  a.push([arr[i], temp[j]].flat());
               };
            } else {
               a.push(arr[i]);
            }
         };

         return a;
      };
   };

   let checkHasId = (obj, id) => {
      if(obj.relations.length === 0) {
         return true;
      };

      for(var i=0;i<obj.relations.length;i++) {
         if(obj.relations[i].items.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
            return true;
         }
      };

      return false;
   };

   return recur(0, null);
};

const data = [
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
];

console.log(getCombinationsById());
```

---

#### Combining Criteria

Assuming that `data` may be only a sample of more data which could have more variation, here is a combined function which can return the results of all of the above, according to which options are used. It can also return results filtering by ID and Level, or by ID or level.

https://jsfiddle.net/xmfjh8s9/

```js
function getCombinationsByMatch(matchId, matchLevel, matchAnd) {
   let recur = (iarray, id, level) => {
      var a = [];
      var temp = [];
      var arr = [];

      if(
         (matchId && (id !== null)) ||
         (matchLevel && (level !== null))
      ) {
         for(var i=0;i<data[iarray].length;i++) {
            if(checkMatch(data[iarray][i], id, level)) {
               arr.push(data[iarray][i]);
            };
         };
      } else {
         arr = data[iarray];
      };

      if(iarray === data.length-1) {
         return (arr);
      } else {

         for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            temp = recur(iarray + 1, arr[i]._id, arr[i].level);

            if(temp.length !== 0) {
               for(var j=0;j<temp.length;j++) {
                  a.push([arr[i], temp[j]].flat());
               };
            } else {
               a.push(arr[i]);
            }
         };

         return a;
      };
   };

   let checkMatch = (obj, id, level) => {
      if(obj.relations.length === 0) {
         return true;
      };

      for(var i=0;i<obj.relations.length;i++) {
         if(
            (
               matchAnd && matchId && matchLevel &&
               (obj.relations[i].items.indexOf(id) !== -1) &&
               (obj.relations[i].level === level)
            ) ||
            (
               !matchAnd && matchId && matchLevel &&
               (
                  (obj.relations[i].items.indexOf(id) !== -1) ||
                  (obj.relations[i].level === level)
               )
            ) ||
            (
               matchId && !matchLevel &&
               (obj.relations[i].items.indexOf(id) !== -1)
            ) ||
            (
               !matchId && matchLevel && 
               (obj.relations[i].level === level)
            )
         ) {
            return true;
         }
      };
      
      return false;
   };

   return recur(0, null, null);
};

const data = [
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "asia",
      "relations": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb",
      "name": "europe",
      "relations": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d5",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "india",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172da4a"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dba0",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "italy",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172db2f"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02669a62a612a172e394"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd26",
      "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fd",
      "name": "malaysia",
      "relations": [
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02639a62a612a172d9d0"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fb"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            "5f6a02649a62a612a172dd23"
          ],
          "level": "5f22c4af80556e32cf0ca8fc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "_id": "5f7c8a000e746271f08f95cf",
      "level": "5f22c4d180556e32cf0ca8ff",
      "name": "digital",
      "relations": []
    }
  ]
];

console.log(getCombinationsByMatch(true, true, true));
```

This should allow more flexibility in how you find different combinations in `data`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. It seems to work just fine, but it doesn't include **digital**, which should be included with all the combinations since it doesn't have any relations.
Maybe I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: I wasn't clear on that. Should all entries without relations be included when filtering and those with relations but not the specific ones be excluded, or is digital just an exception?

Comment: Yes, all entries with no relations should be included.

Comment: Please see my edit, the example I gave in the edit should return an array with 4 combinations. your answer returns an array with 5 combinations instead (the last combination is incomplete but it's there).

Comment: What filtering criteria are you using with that data and what is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see how the data from the first edit relates to the data from the second edit. It looks like the ids and levels have been renamed and the last element has been removed, but I don't see any pattern to why these changes would occur. Could you explain the algorithm you want in steps or in pseudocode, or demonstrate the intended changes in a diagram?

Comment: ignore the first edit. the data in the first edit is too complex, so you can just use the data in the second edit I added also the expected result.

Comment: btw, your code works if i added an extra filter loop: `console.log(getCombinationsByMatch(true, true, true).filter(a => a.length === data.length));`